# IOS 13 headers via PHP

Tags: php, ios, laravel

I am working on push notifications and I write code in PHP that send push notification to IOS. Now I need to send `apns-push-type , apns-priority`  to apns. But I did not find any perfect solution that solve my problem that how I can send the apns-push-type and how I can set the push notification priority. My current code that I write

```
public function sendIOSNotification($tokens, $data, $envoirement = 'production') {
        try {
            $payload = json_encode($this->setIosNotificationDataParameters($data));
            $deviceTokens = str_replace(array(' ', '<', '>'), '', $tokens['ios']);
            // FUNCTION NOTIFICATIONS        
            $ctx = stream_context_create();
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', config('push-notification.appNameIOS.certificate_' . $envoirement));
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'push');
            //send notification 
            $fp = stream_socket_client(
                    config('push-notification.appNameIOS.ios_push_notification_' . $envoirement), $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx
            );
            $res = [];
            foreach ($deviceTokens as $deviceToken) {
                $apple_identifier = 'com.captureInternation.capture';
                $apple_expiry = time() + (20 * 24 * 60 * 60); // 20 days
                $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload . pack("N", "background") . pack("N", $apple_identifier) . pack("N", $apple_expiry) . pack("N", 5);
                $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
                $res = json_encode($result);
            }
            fclose($fp);
            \Log::info("=== Notification sent ====");
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            $this->printException($ex, 'sendIOSNotification');
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to add a Header. But its high prio by default.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Bearer $token","apns-topic: $apns_topic"]); // add apns-priority here
```

From documentation:
The priority of the notification. If you omit this header, APNs sets the notification priority to 10.
Specify 10 to send the notification immediately. A value of 10 is appropriate for notifications that trigger an alert, play a sound, or badge the app’s icon. Specifying this priority for a notification that has a payload containing the content-available key causes an error.
Specify 5 to send the notification based on power considerations on the user’s device. Use this priority for notifications that have a payload that includes the content-available key. Notifications with this priority might be grouped and delivered in bursts to the user’s device. They may also be throttled, and in some cases not delivered.

Or you can use a library: https://samauto.nl/en/apple-push-notification-service-ios/

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

```
$opts = array(
            'http' => array(
            'header' => "apns-topic: {$app_bundle_id}\r\n" .
                "apns-push-type: {$type}\r\n" .
                "apns-priority: 5\r\n"
            )
        );
$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
```